# Getting segmentation fault while outputting the result of the MySQL query

Tags: mysql, c, segmentation-fault

I have a simple program that should print today's day name. It was working, but I made the get_query_result function and after that, it is giving me a segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mysql.h>

#define QUERY_SIZE 1000

void finish_with_error(MYSQL* con)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
    mysql_close(con);
    exit(1);    
}

void get_query_result(MYSQL *con, MYSQL_RES *result, char *query)
{
    if(mysql_query(con, query))
    {
        finish_with_error(con);
    }

    result = mysql_store_result(con);

    if(result == NULL)
    {
        finish_with_error(con);
    }
}

int main()
{
    MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);
    MYSQL_RES *result;
    MYSQL_ROW row;  

    if(con == NULL)
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "mysql_init() failed\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    if(mysql_real_connect(con, "127.0.0.1", "root", "mysqlpassword", "database", 0, NULL, 0) == NULL)
    {
        finish_with_error(con);
    }

    get_query_result(con, result, "SELECT DAYNAME(DATE(NOW()))");
    row = mysql_fetch_row(result);
    printf("%s\n", row[0]);

    mysql_free_result(result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello. Can you run the program in a `debugger`?

Comment: You have to pass the address of the pointer `MYSQL_RES *result` to `get_query_result` if you want to modify the pointer inside the function. Currently the function modifies a local copy of the pointer which does not affect the pointer in `main`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`result` in `main` is not affected by `get_query_result`, in consequence, you end up calling `mysql_free_result` with an uninitialized pointer.

Switch to

```
MYSQL_RES *get_query_result(MYSQL *con, char *query)
{
    MYSQL_RES *result;

    if(mysql_query(con, query))
    {
        finish_with_error(con);
    }

    result = mysql_store_result(con);

    if(result == NULL)
    {
        finish_with_error(con);
    }
    return result;
}
```

and call it like:

```
result = get_query_result(con, "SELECT DAYNAME(DATE(NOW()))");
```